# Receiving an SSIS Error during execution

Tags: ssis

I am getting the following error in the log of the SSIS
"The output column "XXXXXXX" (624) on the non-error output has no corresponding output column on the error output". I did make sure that the column does exist in the database, also went in to the Advanced Editor of the step (First time around I get "The Index is not valid" error, repeat the step second time and able to get in to the editor, went in to the Column Mappings and did make sure that the column is mapped out. I also tried to remove this column from the mapping and still get the same error. Can some one recommend a way to get passed this error?

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem and got around it by deleting the source & destination components and adding them again.

-It has something to do with schema caching